# Load image and change width and height as3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, loader

i want to load image from remote url and synchronicity and change it width and height.

i am using the folowwing code, but it want let me change the width and highet, i think i needto convert the loader to a Bitmap object.

how can i do that, thank you very much.

```
var imageURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(pic); 
var myImageLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
myImageLoader.load(imageURLRequest); 
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(pic);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(urlRequest);
trace(loader.width); // return 0
loader.width =100; //dosent work
allMC[i].img.addChild(loader);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access what the loader loaded, use `loader.content` reference. If you are loading an image, you can retrieve its raw data via `(loader.content as Bitmap).bitmapData`, of course first check if it's so via `if (loader.content is Bitmap)`. Also, you need to do all of this after your loader will finish loading, it'll send an event indicating this.

```
...
loader.load(urlRequest);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
...
private function loaderComplete(e:Event):void {
    // now your image is fully loaded
    trace(loader.content.width);
    // etc etc, whatever you need to do with your image prior to 
    // addressing it from elsewhere.
}
```

Comment: @Yan your issue is with the loop not with the loader

Comment: Well, loading an image always takes time. I think you're using some external image library as source for your images, so yes, in order for you to have a working loop you have to either pre-load your images asynchronously, or send a request for yet another image right as your previous image loads up, this will buy you some time while the user will admire the image that was just loaded and displayed, and it'll not yet be time for your loop to proceed further.

Comment: i found-->    http://www.ilike2flash.com/2011/05/load-multiple-images-in-actionscript-3.html

Comment: the thing is loading multipile images.